# Unable to resolve error in PL/pgSQL with SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I cannot seem to solve this error with a stored procedure. The code works fine outside of the procedure but when I save it to the procedure I receive

> ```
> Error "join_table" is not a known variable
> Line 14: INTO join_table
> ```

If I remove that line everything works perfectly. Appreciate any suggestions or help. The idea is to have the procedure truncate the main 2 tables, drop and recreate the `join_table` based on a trigger to refresh all data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rental_refresh()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
TRUNCATE new_table;
TRUNCATE ts_30;
DROP TABLE join_table;

INSERT INTO new_table (c1, c2, c3,c4,c5)
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4,c5
FROM other_table;

SELECT r.c1,r.c2,cr.c1,cr.c2,cr.c3,cr.c4,cr.sc5
INTO join_table
FROM new_table cr
INNER JOIN r_table r ON cr.c1=r.r1;
END; $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`CREATE TABLE AS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html). Never use use SQL's [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html). Postgres supports it in SQL since it (unfortunately) still is part of standard SQL, but its use is officially discouraged. Read the [notes in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html#id-1.9.3.172.7).

In PL/pgSQL `SELECT INTO` is used to assign variables, hence your error message.

See:

- [Create a temporary table from a selection or insert if table already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850707/create-a-temporary-table-from-a-selection-or-insert-if-table-already-exist/18920372#18920372)
- [SELECT INTO with more than one attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311634/select-into-with-more-than-one-attribution/16311870#16311870)

That said, your `PROCEDURE` does not have to use PL/pgSQL. Could be plain SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rental_refresh()
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$proc$
TRUNCATE new_table;
TRUNCATE ts_30;
DROP TABLE join_table;

INSERT INTO new_table (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4,c5
FROM   other_table;

CREATE TABLE join_table AS
SELECT r.c1,r.c2,cr.c1,cr.c2,cr.c3,cr.c4,cr.sc5
FROM   new_table cr
JOIN   r_table r ON cr.c1 = r.r1;
$proc$
```

(But use `CREATE TABLE AS` in any case.)

See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)