# PL/pgSQL INSERT INTO table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, create-table

I have a plpgsql function that creates an execute statement and I want it to execute it into a table. The standard `EXECUTE ... INTO table_name` didn't work, so I was looking for an alternative. Basically, the select statement returns three columns which I want to save to a table.

Here's some sample code of the execute:

```
query = 'SELECT name, work, phone FROM info WHERE name = '
        || quote_literal(inName) || ' ORDER BY phone';
```

Ideally, if I was just running the query myself I would just put a SELECT INTO tablename, but that didn't work with the execute.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*to execute it into a table*" makes no sense at all

Comment: You can select into tables, why not execute? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html) for that:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE foo AS
   SELECT name, work, phone
   FROM info WHERE name = ' || quote_literal(in_name) || ' ORDER BY phone';
```

`SELECT INTO` is discouraged for that purpose:
[Combine two tables into a new one so that select rows from the other one are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559090/combine-two-tables-into-a-new-one-so-that-select-rows-from-the-other-one-are-ign/15560009#15560009)

`SELECT / EXECUTE .. INTO ..` is meant for *single* rows, not for whole tables in plpgsql.

And the assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`, not `=`.
And a single quote was missing.
And don't use unquoted mixed case identifiers in Postgres.